# Microsoft Visual Studio, which version should I use? Community, Professionals or Enterprise?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

> [image]

[image]

This problem is for Community edition of VS 2022.

I cannot solve the problem. It does not show any project's files and
folders.

Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: It obviously won't show anything if no project is open. Open (or create) a solution and it will work fine.

Comment: Note that for the professional or enterprise versions you need a license.